# Reducing the speed/velocity of a UR5

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm executing the [ros-industrial](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot) launch files on a real UR5 robot but I would like to reduce the speed at which it executes my moveit plans.

Can anyone advice how I can do that from a python package, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318993/reducing-the-speed/velocity-of-a-ur5/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution.

For anyone else looking, in the moveit generated package **config/joint_limits.yaml** file, resides the following configurations:

```
joint_limits:
  shoulder_pan_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 3.15
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 3.15
  shoulder_lift_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 3.15
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 3.15
  elbow_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 3.15
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 3.15
  wrist_1_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 3.2
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 3.2
  wrist_2_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 3.2
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 3.2
  wrist_3_joint:
    has_velocity_limits: true
    max_velocity: 3.2
    has_acceleration_limits: true
    max_acceleration: 3.2
```

I changed all the *3.15* values to **1.00** and the *3.2* values to **1.2**.
Those figures were arbitrary. Not sure it there is a way to set better values but the UR5 is slowed down.

---

Originally posted by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) with karma: 247 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-21**:
Instead of changing the limits, I'd go with setting an appropriate *scaling* value for the velocity and acceleration. MoveIt supports that (methods have `MaxScalingFactor` in them). I'm not sure about Python support though (as I don't use it).

That is much more fiexible, as it allows you to use the full range of velocities that your manipulator supports, instead of limiting it to only very slow velocities.

**Comment by [Ataraxy](https://answers.ros.org/users/65581/ataraxy/) on 2022-04-25**:
But `MaxScalingFactor` doesnt work at `computeCartesianPath`.And i tried to redifined trajectory ,but it didnt work at my real  fanuc_m710ic  robot .So how could i increse the speed of real robot.